# python versions management: always results python 2.7 in console

Tags: python, python-3.6

Several versions of python are installed on my Mac.

Usually, I am using Anaconda with Python 2.7. Nowadays I decide to try Python 3.6

Environment parameters:

```
which python
#/Users/User/anaconda/bin/python

which python3.6 
#/usr/local/bin/python3.6

echo $PATH 
/Users/User/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/User/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

The problem is:

```
~ User$ /usr/local/bin/python3.6 --version
  Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

How can I to overcome this trouble?

Answer (score 3):

The output from the second command where running `python3.6 --version` prints out a Python 2.7.14 string doesn't make sense to me.  You might try removing the Anaconda directories from your `PATH` environment variable and see if that resolves it.

The simplest way to manage and install multiple Python versions is through [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

It allows you to install new versions with `pyenv install <version>` for dozens of Python versions including CPython as well as alternative interpreters like PyPy.

I would recommend you try installing pyenv:

```
$ brew install pyenv
```

Then install Python 3.6.5 via it:

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.5
```

You can set this version as your system-wide default Python version as well:

```
$ pyenv global 3.6.5
```

Then in projects where you want the `python` command to point to a Python 2.7 shim, you can set the local version in that directory with:

```
$ pyenv local 2.7.14
```

With these commands, you can just run `python` in any one of your project directories (after you've set a custom override version if desired), and not have to worry about calling python3.6 in some places, python2.7 in others, etc.

In a more advanced setup, you can also provide multiple Python versions if you have a project that needs both Python 2 and Python 3 together, for example, in a shell session:

```
$ pyenv shell 3.6.5 2.7.14
$ pyenv version
3.6.5 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
2.7.14 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.14
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

(In this case whichever version you set first is the one that `python` points to by default.)